# empty name in directive 'import' in 'NAMESPACE' file

Tags: r, gitlab, package

When trying to install my package from gitlab I am getting the error message

```
Fehler in asChar(e[-1L]) : 
  empty name in directive 'import' in 'NAMESPACE' file
```

resulting in

```
installation of package ‘...’ had non-zero exit status
```

My NAMESPACE file looks as follows:

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

export(daten_generieren)
export(erzeuge_COVID_grafik)
export(num_zsmfassen)
import(dplyr)
import(magrittr)
```

I am not sure what the error message means or how to resolve the issue. I would guess that the error means that do not have any imports but that is of course not the case.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when using devtools::document() and got your weird error message - `Error in asChar(ivars) : empty name in directive 'importFrom' in 'NAMESPACE' file`.

Following advice from roxygen2 github discussion - I removed the NAMESPACE file and rebuilt it with roxygen2 and it went away.

https://github.com/r-lib/roxygen2/issues/1137

Comment: It's maybe worth noting that if you have somewhere a `@exportMethod` tag with nothing after it (as in `@exportMethod` and not like `@exportMethod myFun`), then you will also get this error, and remaking the NAMESPACE will not help.